# On appengine, how do I put an entity in the reducer?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am using:

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

and starting from the demo app.

How should I write an entity to the datastore? Yield a put operation? What should the output writer type be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I used yield with a put operation like this:

```
def makethumbnails(entity):
    if entity.small:
        try:
            entity.thumb = images.resize(entity.small, 80, 100)
        except Exception, e:
            pass
    yield op.db.Put(entity)
```

In my mapreduce.yaml the corresponding elements are

```
- name: makethumbnails
  mapper:
    input_reader: mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader
    handler: main.makethumbnails
    params:
    - name: entity_kind
      default: main.Image
```

That was a combination that worked for me, or if you just want to update a variable for a large number of entities:

```
def seturl(entity):
    if entity.url:
        if entity.url.find('mydomainname') > 1:
            try:
                entity.url = 'www.mydomainname.com'
                yield op.db.Put(entity)
            except Exception, e:
                logging.debug('There occurred exception:%s' % str(e))
```

I could process abt 15000 entities in one job using operations like above.

Comment: Thanks, that's a mapper though? I'm doing it in the reducer. I found that you can not specify the output and not write anything in the reducer and just put there. That works, but it doesn't batch the puts.